# How to change this old functions with the newer functions on itk

Tags: c++, itk

i have this old code and io want to adapt to the newer ITK,

```
typedef itk::Statistics::ScalarImageToListAdaptor<ImageType> ImageListSample;
typedef itk::Statistics::ScalarImageToListAdaptor<MaskImageType> MaskListSample;
typedef itk::Statistics::SelectiveSubsampleGenerator<ImageListSample,MaskListSample>SubsampleGeneratorType;
typedef itk::Statistics::ListSampleToHistogramGenerator<SubsampleGeneratorType::OutputType,float> HistogramGeneratorType;

ImageListSample::Pointer imageListSample = ImageListSample::New();
imageListSample->SetImage(imageReader->GetOutput());

MaskListSample::Pointer maskListSample = MaskListSample::New();
maskListSample->SetImage(thresholdFilter->GetOutput());

SubsampleGeneratorType::ClassLabelVectorType selectedLabels;   
selectedLabels.push_back(itk::NumericTraits<SubsampleGeneratorType::ClassLabelType>::One);

std::cout << "Generating masked subsample" << std::endl;
SubsampleGeneratorType::Pointer subsampleGenerator = SubsampleGeneratorType::New();
subsampleGenerator->SetInput(imageListSample);
subsampleGenerator->SetClassMask(maskListSample);
subsampleGenerator->SetSelectedClassLabels(selectedLabels);
```

what functions replace this one:

ScalarImageToListAdaptor

SelectiveSubsampleGenerator

ListSampleToHistogramGenerator

Comment: Sometimes if you look at notes for a release for itk or paraview you will get information on the replacement. Here is some info that may cover ScalarImageToListAdaptor [https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Proposals:Refactoring_Statistics_Framework_2007_Migration_Users_Guide](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Proposals:Refactoring_Statistics_Framework_2007_Migration_Users_Guide)  I said may because this is old as well and I have not developed in itk recently.

Comment: i have found how to replace a lot of functions using this guide.
I have no clue how to replace SelectiveSubsampleGenerator

Comment: Perhaps look in ITK 3.20 to see what `SelectiveSubsampleGenerator` was doing, and then either reimplement that in your application or port that class to ITKv5 (keeping those headers specific to your application source code).